# Bitcoin ECDSA signing via crypto.sign/4 is producing wrong signature (not RFC6979 compatible)

Tags: cryptography, erlang, bitcoin

I'm trying to sign a bitcoin transaction and part of the process is to sign it with sha256 and private key.

Here's the Elixir/Erlang code that I use:

```
signed_data = :crypto.sign(:ecdsa, :sha256, data, [prk, :secp256k1]) |> Base.encode16
```

which produces the following string:

```
3046022100AFF0CCC46F08C1A2D304483C0D9B97348EEEB7D415E394A512B87A73CB69AA660221009DB8FD52692FD0ADF16F0BB8EA870C9424F1BCD22EB6755388883DE62FBC01BD
```

The problem is that this signature fails against a reference implementation which I use against BlockCypher.

The signature that they provide in the example is like this:

```
3044022045734b7593ed805dd95d3dfb86658afdb647b6693a740ffc9b2aa3d37cc6c06e0220324e5024acc51550e287564c308e280b8978305198d49cb2df8d07e7822b2563
```

**So for the same data/privateKey input parameters my signature is 2 bytes longer. I byte longer in K part and 1 byte in S part.**

I suspect that Erlang crypto library is not following RFC6979 which bitcoin expects.

Here's a link to GO implementation of the signer that works: https://github.com/blockcypher/btcutils/tree/master/signer

The question is: **Is there a way to make Erlang crypto work for this or is there an alternative Erlang/Elixir library that I should be using.**

Comment: So one thing is that your signature is going to be longer in this case, but it is a valid length. the file format calls for 30 (the signature starts here) 44|45|46 (it is so many bytes long) 02 (the first part starts here) 20 | 21 | 22 (it is this many bytes long) then so many bytes, then 02 followed by 20|21|22. So the signature in the example is 44 bytes, or 0220(then 20 bytes)0220(then twenty bytes) and your signature is 46 - 0221(then 21 bytes)0221(then twenty bytes). This is expected and not indicative of an rfc6979 problem as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I could find is this: https://github.com/trustatom-oss/erlang-secp256k1

It is not a native Erlang code and is using NIF and plain C. But it's better than nothing.

Leaving it here just in case somebody does a native Erlang/Elixir implementation. If you do, please ping me.

Answer (score 3):

ECDSA signatures describe a point inside an elliptic curve. In bitcoin's case, the curve is [secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1). For real numbers, such curve looks more or less like this:

[image]

Points inside the curve are unequivocally specified by two values or "coordinates": R and S. For a single R value, there are two possible valid S values.

In October 2015, someone started to take advantage of such duality to manipulate already-broadcasted transactions again and again in order to flood the Bitcoin network and cause it to malfunction.

Due to such malleability potential risks, Blockcypher and other notable members of the Bitcoin scene [immediately decided to embrace](https://blog.blockcypher.com/enforcing-low-s-values-to-eliminate-a-bitcoin-network-attack-3582fc0ae948?gi=e2131bc82365#.rj1vni476) to BIP-0062.

BIP-0062 enforces "low S values". This means that transactions containing signatures which S component is greater than a certain value must be discarded. Such top value is:

```
0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF5D576E7357A4501DDFE92F46681B20A0
```

If you want to make sure your transactions contain always valid S values, you need to check if the resulting S value is greater than the top value. If so, just remove the current S value to the following one:

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141
```

This is an example of a function doing such transformation in Elixir.

```
def enforce_low_s sig do
  len  = sig |> :binary.at(1)
  rlen = sig |> :binary.at(3)
  r    = sig |> :binary.part(4, rlen)
  slen = sig |> :binary.at(rlen + 5)
  s    = sig |> :binary.part(rlen + 6, slen)
  sint = s   |> :binary.decode_unsigned
  if sint > 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF5D576E7357A4501DDFE92F46681B20A0 do
    s = (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141 - sint) |> :binary.encode_unsigned
    slen = s |> :binary.bin_to_list |> Enum.count
    len = rlen + slen + 4
  end
  <<48, len, 2>> <> <<rlen>> <> r <> <<2, slen>> <> s
end
```

Therefore, the complete signing process would look like this:

```
priv_key = "yourhexprivatekey"
    |> Base.decode16!
msg = "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet..."
sig = :crypto.sign(:sha256, msg, [priv_key, :secp256k1])
    |> enforce_low_s
    |> Base.encode16
```

Comment: Adan, could you please produce a full gist of how this is working?

Comment: It still produces different hash from official btc C code